# Screensaver on windows 8 does not work

Tags: windows-8, screensaver

Screensaver on windows 8.1 does not work. What shall I do ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpvIn.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps update the Power Driver and may even BIOS.

Comment: @John Not of much help. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: I am not sure of any other way . I no longer have a Windows 8 machine to try anything.

Comment: @John What about a solution in Win 10 ?

Comment: Update to Windows 10. Screensaver is fine on my two Windows 10 machines and my Windows 11 Preview machine. Windows 8 is getting old so upgrade makes sense.